# Grunt task not found (grunt-contrib-sass)

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-sass

Here's my gruntfile.js, it's in the same directory as `sass/style.scss` and  `package.json`. `package.json` has `grunt`, `grunt-contrib-sass` and `grunt-cli` installed.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    // this is where you set up your Sass settings. Once you know what you're doing, you can change thse.
    Sass: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          style: 'compressed'
        },
        files: {
          'style.css': 'sass/style.scss'
        }
      }
    }
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ["Sass"]);
};
```

Any ideas why I'm receiving the task not found error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Saas` to `saas` as shown in the [example](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass#example-config) config.

*Note: The correct spelling of the Task name starts with a lowercase (`s`).*

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    sass: { // <-- Change to lowercase `s`
      dist: {
        options: {
          style: 'compressed'
        },
        files: {
          'style.css': 'sass/style.scss'
        }
      }
    }
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ["sass"]);  // <-- Change to lowercase `s`
};
```